# Implementing SSL in tomcat Rest Api webapp

Tags: ssl, rest, tomcat9, jks

I'm trying to implement SSL in my tomcat webapp (a rest api), so only certificated routes can make requests to it.

So I created a jks to the server and extracted the certificate (example.cer) with keytool. So I have both server.jks and server.cer in my tomcat folder.

In conf/server.xml I set up this connector.

```
<Connector
      clientAuth="true" port="8443" minSpareThreads="5" maxSpareThreads="75"
      enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
      acceptCount="100" maxThreads="200"
      scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
      keystoreFile="file:///C:/nameOfFolders/apache-tomcat-9.0.12/server.jks"
      keystoreType="JKS" keystorePass="myPassword" keyPass="myPassword"
      truststoreFile="file:///C:/nameOfFolders/apache-tomcat-9.0.12/server.jks"
      truststoreType="JKS" truststorePass="myPassword"
      SSLVerifyClient="require" SSLEngine="on" SSLVerifyDepth="2"       sslProtocol="TLS"
 />
```

And added the following configuration to my rest-api webapp, in the web.xml file:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/my-api/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>example</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Repository</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>example</role-name>
</security-role>
```

My client (an angular application) is also running as tomcat webapp, and can access the rest-api without problems. But I can still access the api using postman, without setting a certificate or other configuration, so that means my-api is not checking for ssl certificates to allow access? What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the URI path of your API? `/<app name>/my-api/*` or `/my-api/*`?

Comment: It is just /my-api/*, e.g.: localhost:8080/my-api/*

Comment: The `<url-pattern>` of  a security contraint is relative to the web application, not the server. Try with `/*`.

Comment: I changed the `<url-pattern>` with `/*` and now it seems to work, it is giving me a bad certificate error (for some reason the tomcat is not using the certificate I generated, but I believe that's another question). Thank you.

Comment: Your browser will reject a self-signed certificate, unless you added it to the system's trusted certificate store.